# AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine server's fully qualified servername error after creating VirtualHost

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, centos8

I have installed an Apache server in CentOS 8 and it was serving both http and https pages correctly, that is, I could view the Apache test page when connected to the server from my browser

I used this tutorial to enable https: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-https-on-apache-centos/

This much worked. But when I tried to enable the server to serve webpages other that the default test page, I am getting the error "AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine server's fully qualified servername error after creating VirtualHost" when trying to restart the apache server using

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

Here are the contents of my /etc/https/conf/http.conf with some comments removed.

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin root@localhost

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
#ServerName www.example.com:80

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

EnableSendfile on

IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

I have a feeling this has something to do with the ServerName entry. It is commented by default as shown above, but I have tried uncommenting it as well as matching it with the coonfiguration in my VirtualHost file, but I am getting the same error.

Here are the contents of the /etc/httpd/sites-available/adorkable.conf

(**NOTE**: the word adorkable has been replaced with my username, username1)

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin email@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/username1/"
    ServerName localhost.localdomain
    ServerAlias username1
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/username1/error.log

<Directory "/var/www/html/username1/">
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Output of systemctl status httpd after issuing a systemctl restart httpd:

```
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-05-14 14:53:28 KST; 43s ago
     Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
  Process: 11746 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 11746 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Reading configuration..."

May 14 14:53:28 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
May 14 14:53:28 localhost.localdomain httpd[11746]: AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
May 14 14:53:28 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 14 14:53:28 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 14 14:53:28 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

How do I restart the httpd service here?

**UPDATE**: the linked tutorial above says that we need to add the following line at the end of httpd.conf

```
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

This is the only change I have made to the default httpd.conf file, and if I comment this line I can restart httpd normally. So the problem is somewhere in my version of the `/etc/httpd/sites-available/adorkable.conf` file (renamed to username1.conf in my case. I have a symlink to this file in sites-enabled, created using the command

```
sudo ln -s /etc/httpd/sites-available/adorkable.conf /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/adorkable.conf
```

as instructed in the linked tutorial.

Comment: Try removing ServerName from virtualhost

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana didn't work, i tried removing ServerName, ServerAlias, ServerAdmin; same error

Comment: instead of `sudo ln -s /etc/httpd/sites-available/adorkable.conf /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/adorkable.conf `, you could also try using just the command `a2ensite adorkable`. But I don't think it makes a difference

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana I don't ave a2ensite command

Comment: oh ok. I though you were using Ubuntu, sorry

Comment: If you would've asked me somehow, I would've given you way easier steps. But. Let me just test myself

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana please share a link if available

Comment: This is not related to ServerName

Comment: Oh my god, I didn't realise. Check apache error log

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana last entry says (13)Permission Denied: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /var/www/html/username1/error.log. Unable to open log. Looks like a folder permission issue but i'm not sure how to fix it

Comment: Oh. Then the path to error log is wrong

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana yes error log is at /var/log/httpd/error_log

Comment: Remove ErrorLog from virtualhost. And try. Does /var/www/html/username1/error.log exist? Try running `chown apache:apache /var/www/html/username1/error.log` only if apache restart is successful after removing the ErrorLog.

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana it's working. Thanks a lot. What should be done to enable writing to ErrorLog?

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana the username1 folder has these properties using ls -l: drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root 109. Is this causing this problem? In the GUI file explorer there is a lock on the folder so I think that is causing this problem.

Comment: I will post this as answer if you wish to accept it. But, try to run that command with `sudo` at the start, so `sudo chown apache:apache /var/www/html/username1/error.log`

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana should it just be sudo chown apache:apache /var/www/html/username1/ ? becasue in the beginning I don't think error.log exists

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana please post as answer so I can accept, as this is what fixed the problem for me

Comment: Yes you are right. You can either do that or mine. Because error.log was not created by you, you must run your command `sudo chown apache:apache /var/www/html/username1/ -R` that would fix every issue here

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana I've just tried sudo chown apache:apache /var/www/html/username1/ -R, and it doesn't work. If I enable the ErrorLog line again I get the same error even after doing sudo chown apache:apache

Comment: Try going inside username1, and running `cat > error.log` and pressing Ctrl+D.

Answer (score 2):

Remove ErrorLog from virtualhost. And try. As /var/www/html/username1/error.log doesn't exist. Try running `chown apache:apache /var/www/html/username1 -R` only if apache restart is successful after removing the ErrorLog directive. After you run the command, try adding back the ErrorLog directive, I believe it should work.

Comment: I asked "How do I restart the httpd service here?" Apache is not restarting. And I don't have "httpd.conf/apache2.conf" I have "/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf"

Comment: Ok then. Add it to httpd.conf

Comment: Thank you for the update but even after doing chown, if I add back the ErrorLog directive I get the same error.

Comment: Lets talk in this comment. Lets not continue in the above comments. It is too long, so

Comment: Try going inside username1, and running `cat > error.log` and pressing Ctrl + D. Then try restarting. Make sure error.log is owned by "apache"

Comment: Let me know about the results

Comment: I replied in the chatroom, with more details

Comment: Actually what ended up working for me is here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/129517/41756, see the comments on that answer

Comment: That was exactly what I was going to say LOL. I didn't say it because I focused on resolving the problem instead of changing. Upto you if y ou want to accept the answer, just to close this.